# Update Facebook Status From Android App

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I have a quick question I have spent countless hours trying to search for an answer and have come up with a blank. I am developing an Android app and I would like it to update the users status NOT post to their wall. Everything I find explains how to post a message to the users wall. But I want to update their status on the news feed. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: I think this may have been moved to a more timeline specific function, also api accessible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I am no expert but it seems that posting on your own wall will update their status in the news feed?

Regardless, looking at Facebook's Hackbook example (available in their GIT repo), their "Update Status" function is simply a wall post:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("caption", getString(R.string.app_name));
            params.putString("description", getString(R.string.app_desc));
            params.putString("picture", Utility.HACK_ICON_URL);
            params.putString("name", getString(R.string.app_action));

            Utility.mFacebook.dialog(Hackbook.this, "feed", params, new UpdateStatusListener());
```